# Make mass updates via Maximo list view?

Tags: maximo

Maximo 7.6.1.1:

It would be great if there were a way to make **mass updates** to a field in a table from within Maximo applications.

For example, in **other software** such as GIS software, it is possible to open the attribute table of a table, filter the rows, and perform mass updates with [a tool called the Field Calculator](https://youtu.be/nQGlcxissEU?t=23).

---

So in Maximo terms, I might:

1. Open the Assets application --> List view.
2. Do a filter or advanced query on the assets.
3. Click an action.
4. The action would open a dialog that would allow me to select a field name.
5. I would enter text or a number as a constant. Or use JavaScript to write an expression.
6. Hit Run.
7. The filtered rows would be updated.

---

I'm aware that there is a homegrown method for doing this in Maximo where a user can export to Excel, update the values in Excel, and import the updated Excel sheet back into Maximo. However, that seems unnecessarily clunky to me.

Is there a way to make mass updates to filtered rows **from within Maximo applications**?

---

**Edit:**

An answer can be found here:

[Maximo bulk update from List view](https://bportaluri.com/2021/10/maximo-bulk-update-list-view.html)

Comment: The change status dialog does something like this, in that you can mass apply a change status to everything on the list screen. With a bean class customization (or maybe with an automation script using that newly added link to the app bean) you could create the same thing for your field(s) of choice, but I don't know if this is the kind of solution you were referring to.

Comment: Have you asked IBM's support already?

Comment: @TiagoMartinsPeres I've submitted a request for enhancements, yes.

Comment: So you know already that's something one can't do or you just assumed that?

Answer (score 3):

Prior to 7.6.1, you would have needed to develop a custom bean class in order to be read the filtered records in the list-view.

In the past, I have developed a generic bean class that called an automation script (referenced in the application's XML), where all of the business logic is implemented (in the script only). Hence, I was able to use this class in many places with different automation scripts.

I have written some articles on LinkedIn about this: https://www.linkedin.com/in/amir-samir-1ba73725/

Now, with the release of 7.6.1, it seems that IBM has added support for the UI in automation scripts, and hence, you don't need the bean class.

More information here:
[Access the UI via an automation script (using getWebClientSession)](https://community.ibm.com/community/user/communities/community-home/digestviewer/viewthread?GroupId=727&MessageKey=72fedf74-7167-42aa-af41-2e79b70dc7b7)

Note: I believe formulas are of no use in your case.

Comment: Interesting... Can you post a direct link to your generic bean class article please?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you are referring to this? https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/maximo-application-importexport

I would recommend MxLoader because it is easier to use. Other than what @Dex said to use custom java or Automation Script, I don't see a way to do this from within Maximo.

Asset YTD costs can be updated using BIRT, but I personally using a reporting tool is bad practice. If you want, that's another option (although I warn against it).

Comment: Regarding using a BIRT report to make mass updates: Is this functionality invoked by clicking a hyperlink? In other words, is the logic/instructions contained in a URL?

Comment: I am not sure. The report is Asset Roll Up Cost (standard out of the box Maximo BIRT report).